# Extracting with Regex in Yahoo pipes

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I am trying to use Yahoo pipes and remove everything from "Article" till the end of the page. 
If I use Regex exp Article.+ I can extract everything till the end of line which is till "2011

" . But I need to extract till the end of the page which is till "url.replace"
What am I doing wrong. I am using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ which is awesome

Here is what the section of the page looks like
This Article was reviewed by Brown Last updated on: Oct 2, 2011

'; _url = _url.replace

Thanks
Hil

Comment: You should probably edit this question to include the text you're matching and a link to your pipe

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it:
query string is:
Article.+

this will extract till end of line
If one wants to extract till end of page use the S checkbox in Yahoo Pipes